# Does p(a,b,c)=p(a,b)p(a,c) hold when b and c are independent?

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading through a thesis, it states that given $b$ and $c$ being independent:

\begin{equation}
p(a\mid b,c) := p(a\mid b) p(a\mid c)
\end{equation}

This would imply just using the definition of a conditional probability:

\begin{equation}
\frac{p(a,b,c)}{p(b,c)} = \frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)} \frac{p(a,c)}{p(c)}
\end{equation}

Now, assuming independence between $b$ and $c$ the denominator $p(b,c)=p(b)p(c)$ can be crossed out, and the following has to hold:

\begin{equation}
p(a,b,c) = p(a,b) p(a,c)
\end{equation}

Does this actually hold if $b$ and $c$ are independent? If so, how? And if not, how would this constraint be called? It's not pairwise independence. It is between a pair of two variables out of a set of three.

Comment: Actually now I think about it, if everything would be mutually independent $p(a,b,c)=p(a)p(b)p(c)$. There is one $a$ "too much" in the equation in the question. It is probably not true, and this constraint has no name. Maybe I have to remove this question.

Comment: No, keep it, it's a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this actually hold if $b$ and $c$ are independent?

No. A standard counterexample is when $b$ and $c$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli $\pm1$ and $a=bc$, then $p(a=-,b=+,c=+)=0$ while $p(a=-,b=+)=p(a=-,c=+)=\frac14$.

> And if not, how would this constraint be called?

Dunno. The constraint $p(a,b,c)p(a)=p(a,b)p(a,c)$ is the conditional independence of $b$ and $c$ conditionally on $a$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That would make sense.